# How do I escape a comma when using a markup extension?

Tags: wpf, escaping, markup-extensions

The value of the second parameter of the markup extension I am using is a string containing some commas and I don't want those commas to be interpreted as parameter separators by the xaml interpreter / parser, but that the whole string as such including the commas is used as value.

Here is an example:

```
<SomeControl SomeProperty="{Wpf:MyExtension MyFirstParameter, 
                                            MySecondParameter, being a string, containing some commas.}" />
```

Google didn't help, I found some similar issues but none apply to this problem:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms744986.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use single quotes to encapsulate a string; so your mark-up should look something like:

```
<SomeControl SomeProperty="{Wpf:MyExtension MyFirstParameter, 
                           'MySecondParameter, being a string, containing some commas.'}" />
```

I'm not sure whether you will also need the `{}` escape sequence mark-up.

Comment: And I thought I tried that... Thanks a lot, that does the job.

Comment: You do still need a leading {} if a left brace immediately follows the left apostrophe. I just had this exact case and it won't even compile without it. E.g., '{}{0:N0}, that is cool'